# why when exporting a model from blender to Unity does Model break?

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, blender

again...
I trying to export model from blender to unity, and everything's ok.(model)[image: 1]]
But the model in unity breaks, the walls disappear depending on the angle of the camera.(view from unity)[image: 2]]
What is the problem?
All export rules from blender to unity are followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to normals, your walls have a normal that points in one direction on either side but not both.

Two solutions:

i) Extrude walls so that you can have a normal pointing on each side

ii) Make a material/shader with cull off parameter so that backface culling is disabled when rendering the object